# How to get one specific column from datatable into model in MVC Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, model-view-controller

I would like to grab all of the skills that an employee has rated themselves on from the database by SkillId. I currently have all of the fields in the Ratings table stored in the model but would like to get out only the SkillId but it tells me that it Rating does not contain a definition for SkillId.

```
model.EmployeeRatings = db.Ratings.Where(r => r.EmployeeId == User.Identity.Name.Remove(0, 8))
                                  .OrderBy(s => s.SkillId);
```

(this is storing all of the fields in the Ratings table by the EmployeeId of the user)

I can do this by putting it in a foreach loop on the view and getting all of the SkillIds but want to have this data stored in the model so that I can easily put it into a HTML.DropDownListFor() in the view.

Is it possible to grab only the SkillId out of the Ratings table in the model and omit all of the rest of the data from the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you're just looking for `Select`:

```
...OrderBy(s => s.SkillId).Select(s => s.SkillId);
```

However, if this is going to be used for a select list, anyways, you might as well build an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` right from the start:

```
.Select(s => new SelectListItem { Value = s.SkillId.ToString(), Text = s.SkillName });
```

Comment: After changing the view model to IEnumerable<SelectListItem> and trying to run the code after changing it to suggested code, it gives me the error: "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression"

Comment: That has nothing to do with where the `Select` statement is at. The error literally tells you what the problem is. When you select `SkillId` you end up with an `IEnumerable<long>` (since `SkillId` is apparently of type `long`), which can't be stored in a property of type `IEnumerable<Rating>`: `long` is not the same thing as `Rating`. You need to add another property to store this into of the proper type or use something else like `ViewBag`.

Comment: Great thank you! I think that I have figure it out by changing the type in the View Model to IEnumerable<long> instead of <Rating>

Comment: "LINQ to Entities does not recognise" the `Select =>new SelectListItem` - so do something that the LINQ to Entities does like and then convert to select list item after, ie:  `.OrderBy(s=>s.SkillId).Select(s => new { s.SkillId, s.SkillName).ToList().Select(x=>new SelectListItem { Value = x.SkillId, Text = x.SkillName });`  The `ToList` in the middle tells EF to go ahead and convert to that point to SQL and run the SQL, then it takes the result (which is just the two fields) and converts them to SelectListItem.